# Convert month name to decimal using 'to_datetime' function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe *data* that contains the column 'month':

```
      year      month  passengers
0    1949    January         112
1    1949   February         118
2    1949      March         132
3    1949      April         129
4    1949        May         121
```

I would like to convert the *month* column to zero-padded decimal number, so I use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(data['month'], format= '%B')
```

I expect this will convert the month names to zero-padded decimals, but instead I get the following:

```
0     1900-01-01
1     1900-02-01
2     1900-03-01
3     1900-04-01
4     1900-05-01
```

I guess I can use regex to extrapolate the month number from the returned data, but I imagine there has to be a cleaner way to do this.

I am somewhat new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Many thanks for reading.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(data['month'], format= '%B').dt.month`

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. Please post as answer and I will mark it.

Comment: @Anurag Close, but it does not pad the decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["months"] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format= '%B').dt.strftime("%m")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   year     month  passengers months
0  1949   January         112     01
1  1949  February         118     02
2  1949     March         132     03
3  1949     April         129     04
4  1949       May         121     05
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newer pandas version(0.23.0+ and later ), even you don't require `strftime` for this operation, and you can use `dt.month:` or `dt.month_name` as required.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'month_name': ['January', 'February' , 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']})

print(df)
   month_name
0     January
1    February
2       March
3       April
4         May
5        June
6        July
7      August
8   September
9     October
10   November
11   December
```

Now, you can simply use `dt.month` as follows.

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month_name, format='%B').dt.month
print(df)
   month_name  month
0     January      1
1    February      2
2       March      3
3       April      4
4         May      5
5        June      6
6        July      7
7      August      8
8   September      9
9     October     10
10   November     11
11   December     12
```